# PostgresSQL agregar elementos

Tags: json, postgresql

Necesito formar el json de esta manera en PostgreSQL.

```
ubi_json json;

  FOR i IN 0..7 LOOP

    ubi_json = ubi_json || to_json('valor',i);

  END LOOP;
```

Sale error:

```
Error : no existe la función to_json(unknown, integer)
```

Necesito esto:

```
[
    { "valor": 1 },
    { "valor": 2 },
    { "valor": 3 },
    { "valor": 4 },
    { "valor": 5 },
    { "valor": 6 },
    { "valor": 7 },
    { "valor": 8 },
    { "valor": 9 },
    { "valor": 10 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno yo nunca he intentado concatenar el json de esa manera(no se si se pueda).
Te recomiendo que trabajes esa variable "ubi_json" en TEXT y vayas armando tu json, ya cuando al tengas armada la casteas "ubi_json::JSON"

```
ubi_json JSON;
tmp_json text := '[';
FOR i IN 0..7 LOOP
    tmp_json = tmp_json || '{"valor":' || i::text || '},'
END LOOP;

SELECT (RTRIM(tmp_json, ',') || ']')::JSON INTO ubi_json;
```

Comment: Me parece muy buena idea.! Excelente de tu parte. Sabes logré hacer esto:

Comment: ubi_json json[];
FOR l IN 1..7 LOOP
          ubi_json = ubi_json || json_build_object('valor',i);
END LOOP;